# fwrite if file doesn't exist?

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

Is it possible to only write a file in PHP if it doesn't exist?

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,"Some Code Here");
fclose($file);
```

So if the file does exist the code won't write the code but if the file doesn't exist it will create a new file and write the code

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with a mode of `x` instead of `w`, which will make fopen fail if the file already exists. The advantage to checking like this compared to using `file_exists` is that it will not behave wrong if the file is created between checking for existence and actually opening the file. The downside is that it (somewhat oddly) generates an E_WARNING if the file already exists.

In other words (with the help of @ThiefMaster's comment below), something like;

```
$file = @fopen("test.txt","x");
if($file)
{
    echo fwrite($file,"Some Code Here"); 
    fclose($file); 
}
```

Comment: I guess you need `@fopen(...)` to suppress the warning thrown.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks, my PHP is apparently rusty when I forgot about _that_ :)

Answer (score 5):

Check with file_exists($filename) if the file exist before you execute your code.

```
if (!file_exists("test.txt")) {
    $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
    echo fwrite($file,"Some Code Here");
    fclose($file); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a variable called $file. This variable contains the name of the file that we want to create.

Using PHP’s is_file function, we check to see if the file already exists or not.

If is_file returns a boolean FALSE value, then our filename does not exist.

If the file does not exist, we create the file using the function file_put_contents.

```
//The name of the file that we want to create if it doesn't exist.
$file = 'test.txt';

//Use the function is_file to check if the file already exists or not.
if(!is_file($file)){
    //Some simple example content.
    $contents = 'This is a test!';
    //Save our content to the file.
    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
}
```

Comment: Please [credit your sources](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-create-file-if-not-exists/)